# How to pipe multiple files to ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, filepath, piping, mov

I am trying to make a bash script that searches all subfolders on given path for .mov files and converts them with ffmpeg and outputs them in an destination folder, keeping the clip name.

I'm very new to scripting and I'm having a hard time finding out how to solve this.

So far I've tried using ls and find to output the filepaths, but have no idea how to pipe this to ffmpeg in the right way.

Any clues?

Edit:

got some sucess with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "drop source folder: "
read source

echo "drop destination folder: "
read des

find "$source" -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -an "$des/${0%%.mov}.mov"' {} \;
exit;
```

but, the it seems to output to the source folder asking for a overwrite. How can i setup the parameters correctly so it outputs to the "destination folder" and keeps the filenames?

Comment: You can create a small program in C++/Java that holds the file references in an array and calls ffmpeg whilst passing on the references one by one in a loop.

Comment: @devnull this is what i have so far, from a little copy paste searching around for similar problems...
#!/bin/bash

echo "drop source folder: "
read source

echo "drop destination folder: "
read des

find "$source" -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -an "${0%%.mov}.mov"' {} \;
exit;

just need to know how to set the destination variable to the ffmpeg to check if it works. how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob || {
    echo "Unable to enable exglob."
    exit 1
}

TARGETEXT='.avi'
TARGETPREFIX='/path/to/somewhere/' ## Make sure it ends with /.

while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    BASE=${FILE##*/}
    NOEXT=${BASE%.*}
    TARGETFILEPATH=${TARGETPREFIX}${NOEXT}${TARGETEXT}
    echo ffmpeg -i "$FILE" "$TARGETFILEPATH"  ## Remove echo if it's already correct.
done < <(exec find -type f -name '*.mov')  ## You could also use -iname '*.sh' instead.
```

Of course you could use a custom directory to search for the files:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name '*.mov'
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the job:

`for f in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "/desination/${f%.mov}.mp4"; done`

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think this works when all the movs are in different subfolers. 

Ive hade success with this:  

#!/bin/bash

echo "drop source folder: "
read source

echo "drop destination folder: "
read des

find "$source" -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -an "${0%%.mov}.mov"' {} \;
exit;

but i dont know where to put my destination variable so all the converted movs goes there. ?

Comment: Your destination variable is $des. You should modify "${0%%.mov}.mov" to "$des/${0%%.mov}.mov"

Comment: i tried that, but in my test setup ffmpeg ask me if i want to overwrite, wich is weird since theres nothing in the destination folder I specified... seems like it outputs to the source folder.